# Flutter: Using Proguard with Gradle 7.0.4

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, proguard

I just updated to Gradle 7.0.4 and upon build I now get the error.

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
No signature of method: build_9gq7rvxos4tcg7upa17qqy1oj.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_9gq7rvxos4tcg7upa17qqy1oj$_run_closure3) values: [build_9gq7rvxos4tcg7upa17qqy1oj$_run_closure3@558fca1c]
```

As the error pointed to the android{} tag in my app/build.gradle I tried commenting out different sections of the android{} tag. I managed to get rid of the error by commenting out Proguard:

```
android {

   /* More code */  

   buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            // These lines seem to have caused the error:
            // minifyEnabled true
            // useProguard true
            // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   }
}
```

However, I would still like to use proguard so my question is what I have to change in my code to make this happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'useProguard' line has ben removed, as of Gradle 7.0.0. Flutter should obfuscate without this, but you can add `shrinkResources true`, if you want.

Android [R8](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html) is an alternative to using Proguard, with its own settings; as long as you're configuring this, you might want to look into switching.